# Cannot make page-bottom width 100%

Tags: magento2, css, full-width

I am trying to set width of page-bottom to be 100% but unfortunately I am still unable to make it 100%.

[image]

what I really want to have is:

[image]

Here is my default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
    <block class="Senheng\Def\Block\Html\Subscribe"
        name="senheng.page.buttom"
        template="Senheng_Default::html/subscribe.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

My subscribe.phtml

```
<div style="width:100%; padding:15px;">

    <img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/send.png');?>" style="float:left" />

    <p>Be the first to find about exclusive offers & get 10% off your first purchase</p>

</div>
```

[image]

What can I do to make that element width (page-bottom) become 100%.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can do it with custom css

Comment: I did, but still the same, look at my inline css

Comment: you can try overriding the parent div class width, like `.page-bottom{
 width: 100% !important; }`

Comment: hi @magefms , it better now after I given !important but still not 100%

Comment: @magefms I just updated the image in the question

Comment: remove padding left and right or set it to 0px

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93706/discussion-between-magefms-and-yusuf-ibrahim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, for .page-bottom , max-width:1280px; is set. If you set max-width:100%, your footer will occupy entire width